# GetIfTable results change after Windows updates on certain computers?

Tags: delphi, ethernet, uniqueidentifier

I'm using the following Delphi code to get a list of MAC addresses on the computer. The hash of the MACs are used to generate an identifier unique to the computer.

My problem is that on some computers (1 out of 50), after Windows 10 updates, I get a different hash than before (result of GetIfTable changes). Physically, there is nothing changed on the computer - no new cards or devices are attached to the computer, but the result is different.

Any ideas on what might be causing this problem?

```
unit ethernet_address;

interface

uses classes, sysutils;

const
     MAX_INTERFACE_NAME_LEN             = $100;
     ERROR_SUCCESS                      = 0;
     MAXLEN_IFDESCR                     = $100;
     MAXLEN_PHYSADDR                    = 8;

     MIB_IF_OPER_STATUS_NON_OPERATIONAL = 0 ;
     MIB_IF_OPER_STATUS_UNREACHABLE     = 1;
     MIB_IF_OPER_STATUS_DISCONNECTED    = 2;
     MIB_IF_OPER_STATUS_CONNECTING      = 3;
     MIB_IF_OPER_STATUS_CONNECTED       = 4;
     MIB_IF_OPER_STATUS_OPERATIONAL     = 5;

     MIB_IF_TYPE_OTHER                  = 1;
     MIB_IF_TYPE_ETHERNET               = 6;
     MIB_IF_TYPE_TOKENRING              = 9;
     MIB_IF_TYPE_FDDI                   = 15;
     MIB_IF_TYPE_PPP                    = 23;
     MIB_IF_TYPE_LOOPBACK               = 24;
     MIB_IF_TYPE_SLIP                   = 28;

     MIB_IF_ADMIN_STATUS_UP             = 1;
     MIB_IF_ADMIN_STATUS_DOWN           = 2;
     MIB_IF_ADMIN_STATUS_TESTING        = 3;


type

   MIB_IFROW            = Record
     wszName : Array[0 .. (MAX_INTERFACE_NAME_LEN*2-1)] of char;
     dwIndex              : LongInt;
     dwType               : LongInt;
     dwMtu                : LongInt;
     dwSpeed              : LongInt;
     dwPhysAddrLen        : LongInt;
     bPhysAddr : Array[0 .. (MAXLEN_PHYSADDR-1)] of Byte;
     dwAdminStatus        : LongInt;
     dwOperStatus         : LongInt;
     dwLastChange         : LongInt;
     dwInOctets           : LongInt;
     dwInUcastPkts        : LongInt;
     dwInNUcastPkts       : LongInt;
     dwInDiscards         : LongInt;
     dwInErrors           : LongInt;
     dwInUnknownProtos    : LongInt;
     dwOutOctets          : LongInt;
     dwOutUcastPkts       : LongInt;
     dwOutNUcastPkts      : LongInt;
     dwOutDiscards        : LongInt;
     dwOutErrors          : LongInt;
     dwOutQLen            : LongInt;
     dwDescrLen           : LongInt;
     bDescr     : Array[0 .. (MAXLEN_IFDESCR - 1)] of Char;
     end;

function Get_EthernetAddresses: TStringList;

Function GetIfTable( pIfTable : Pointer;
                 VAR pdwSize  : LongInt;
                     bOrder   : LongInt ): LongInt; stdcall;


implementation

Function GetIfTable; stdcall; external 'IPHLPAPI.DLL';

function Get_EthernetAddresses: TStringList;
const
   _MAX_ROWS_ = 20;

type
   _IfTable = Record
                 nRows : LongInt;
                 ifRow : Array[1.._MAX_ROWS_] of MIB_IFROW;
              end;

VAR
   pIfTable  : ^_IfTable;
   TableSize : LongInt;
   tmp       : String;
   i,j       : Integer;
   ErrCode   : LongInt;
begin
   pIfTable := nil;
   //------------------------------------------------------------
   Result:=TStringList.Create;
   if Assigned(Result) then
   try
      //-------------------------------------------------------
      // First: just get the buffer size. 
      // TableSize returns the size needed.
      TableSize:=0; // Set to zero so the GetIfTabel function 
                    // won't try to fill the buffer yet, 
                    // but only return the actual size it needs.
      GetIfTable(pIfTable, TableSize, 1);
      if (TableSize < SizeOf(MIB_IFROW)+Sizeof(LongInt)) then
      begin
         Exit; // less than 1 table entry?!
      end; // if-end.

      // Second: 
      // allocate memory for the buffer and retrieve the 
      // entire table.
      GetMem(pIfTable, TableSize);
      ErrCode := GetIfTable(pIfTable, TableSize, 1);
      if ErrCode<>ERROR_SUCCESS then
      begin
         Exit; // OK, that did not work. 
               // Not enough memory i guess.
      end; // if-end.

      // Read the ETHERNET addresses.
      for i := 1 to pIfTable^.nRows do
      try
         if pIfTable^.ifRow[i].dwType=MIB_IF_TYPE_ETHERNET then
         begin
            tmp:='';
            for j:=0 to pIfTable^.ifRow[i].dwPhysAddrLen-1 do
            begin
               tmp := tmp + format('%.2x', 
                      [ pIfTable^.ifRow[i].bPhysAddr[j] ] );
            end; // for-end.
            //-------------------------------------
            if Length(tmp)>0 then Result.Add(tmp);
         end; // if-end.
      except
         Exit;
      end; // if-try-except-end.
   finally
      if Assigned(pIfTable) then FreeMem(pIfTable,TableSize);
   end; // if-try-finally-end.
end;

end.

// ************************ //
Note: this is where we display a part of the Ethernet string as a test. This is what changes after Windows updates, but only on certain computers!
// ************************ //
StringList := Get_EthernetAddresses;
try
  if (StringList.Count > 0) and (Length(StringList.Strings[0]) >= 6) then
  begin
    EthernetPartStr := Copy(StringList.Strings[0], 5, 2);
    //Problem is here, Label10 will change after a Windows update
    Label10.Caption := EthernetPartStr[1] + EthernetPartStr[2] + ' - ' + StringList.Strings[0];
  end;
finally
  StringList.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Where is your definition of `MIB_IFROW`?  Why is your definition of `GetIfTable` missing arguments?  It won't compile this way... can we see your real code?

Comment: What does your hash code look like? Assuming the interfaces are not changing after the update, the only reasonable conclusion is that the MAC addresses themselves are changing.  Some devices do use randomized MACs for (supposed) better security. Or maybe Windows is simply uninstalling and then reinstalling interfaces during the update, thus generating new MACs. Hard to say for sure, since you have not shown your output. Did you verify the list of MACs is actually the same before and after the update?

Comment: Assuming you are using this for licensing? I have seen too many issues with license protection and nothing hurts more than obstructing customers who paid for the license from working because license protection breaks. Mac addresses do change, e.g. new one gets added or users work on different devices and software gets installed or streamed on demand. Users who do not want to pay will still cheat as it's easy to hack. So my 5c: it's not worth it, trust your users.

Comment: Can someone reopen this question? It has been edited

Comment: Most likely cause: the order of the returned list of MAC addresses has changed…